# Making a class attribute into a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, class-attributes

I know what the problem is, i just don't know how to fix it. I've googled how to make a class attribute into a string and I can't find anything. I know it's trying to add a class attribute to a string but how do I make self.mystring into a string so I can add strings together?

I put comments on what I thought was happening in my code. Thank you.

```
def capitalize(self):
        cap = "" #initializing cap
        sentence = str(self.mystring) #typecasting self.mystring into a string
        cap = cap + sentence[0].upper + sentence[1:] #adding "" + capital letter + rest of sentence
        return cap # returning the end result
```

error message: cap = cap + sentence[0].upper + sentence[1:]

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method' objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parens after `upper` -- it's a method of string.

```
cap = cap + sentence[0].upper() + sentence[1:] #adding "" + capital letter + rest of sentence
```